# ionic: print each photo in a row

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new with ionic I want to print each photo in the gallery in a row

```html
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
        <img [src]="photo.data" />
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>`
```

this print all the photos side by side however what I want is to have each photo in a row

more formally I want this:

```
  `Foreach photo in photos 
      print the photo in an ion-row`
```

how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it works

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
        <ion-col>
           <img [src]="photo.data" />
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 4 many things are changed. Just replace `size="6"` with `col-6`.
With this, you will get 2 photos in each row but you are after one photo show in each row then try second example.
ex-1:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
        <img [src]="photo.data" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

ex-2:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
      <ion-col>
        <img [src]="photo.data" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Also, you can use ionic card view, it will look better view:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
      <ion-card>
        <img [src]="photo.data" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: but this doesn't answer the question